# converting to redux tool kit and getting "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.push is not a function"

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

i'm stuck while converting an old project to redux tool kit getting an "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.push is not a function" error. i haven't got to grips with the action/thunk and reducer immutability yet. The alerts are working but then the error msg.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from '../alerts/alertSlice';

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    registerSuccess: (state, action) => {
      const { payload } = action.payload;
      state.push({
        payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
      });
    },
    registerFail: (state, action) => {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      state.push({
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loading: false,
        user: null,
      });
    },
  },
});

const { registerSuccess, registerFail } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;

// Register User
export const register =
  ({ name, email, password }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'comtent-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config);

      dispatch({
        type: registerSuccess,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      const errors = err.response.data.errors;

      if (errors) {
        errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
      }

      dispatch(registerFail());
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.push` is an array function to add a new item at the end of an array - your state is not an array.

You probably wanted to do something along the lines of

```js
        state.token = null
        state.isAuthenticated = false
        state.loading = false
        state.user = null
```

Comment: getting the state change now but getting ``` A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `type`. Value: 
function actionCreator() 
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  
Object { type: actionCreator()
 }
  ```  and the inspector is showing undefined.